# Machine learning model in sklearn is overfitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to make a simple MLP classifier in Sklearn ( with python ) to binary predict which ligand a protein will bind. But I have a problem with the score. I think my classifier is slightly overfitting and I dont know why. It also doesnt really evaluate I think..it just runs through the 6th cell ( with the MLP and grid ) in like a few seconds and thats it. I Also dont know how to get the recall and f1 score ( classification report doesnt work because of some samples size error) I wanted to ask if anyone could help me with if this short evaluation time is normal, and if with the overfitting and how to get the f1 and recall score. My full code is here : https://github.com/Rimhunter/MachineLearning/blob/master/Proteinbinding%20ML%20firsttimeworking%20(5).ipynb

Down below is my cross validation, my SMOTE for the oversampling since I have a huge imbalance on one class, and the classifier.

```
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5)
classifier = MLPClassifier(early_stopping = True)

print(format(sum(b_train==1)))
print(format(sum(b_train==0)))
print(format(sum(b_train==2)))

sm = SMOTE(random_state = 0)
a_train_res, b_train_res = sm.fit_sample(a_train, b_train.ravel())
print(format(a_train_res.shape))
print(format(b_train_res.shape))
print(format(sum(b_train_res==1)))
print(format(sum(b_train_res==0)))
print(format(sum(b_train_res==2)))

params ={ 'hidden_layer_sizes': [(30,)]} #testing different parameters #max_iter maybe?

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, cv = cv, param_grid = params,  
                    return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(a_train_res, b_train_res)



cv_results = pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)
print(cv_results)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [this article on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would like to help you debug your model, but as your question is currently structured, it does not conform to SO question guidelines. It should include a minimal, verifiable example in the post. The link you provided leads to a pretty long Jupyter Notebook (mostly because of cell output and commented cells).

Comment: hope it helps, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html. Explore sklearn.metrics module.